# ggplot2: qplot facet axis scale free while preserving the grid

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following plot (borrowed from http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html):

[image: plot with facet and fixed axis]

Created by the following code:

```
library(ggplot2) 

# create factors with value labels 
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
                      labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
                    labels=c("Automatic","Manual")) 
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
                     labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

q <- qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, size=I(3), facets=gear~cyl,
      xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
print(q)
```

Now I'd like the axis to "scale better". For example the 3 gears column axis could be scaled to a range from 10 to 25. However I still want to preserve the cyl-gears-grid and I want only one scale per column.

So the following does **not** what I expect:

```
q <- qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, size=I(3),
      xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon")
q <- q + facet_wrap(facets=gear~cyl, scales="free_y")
print(q)
```

[image: plot with facet and destroyed grid]

Is there a way to achieve this with ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only one scale for each column or row then you should use `facet_grid()` instead of `facet_wrap()` because for `facet_wrap()` each facet with `scales="free"` is treated independently and just aligned in the number of columns you set.

```
qplot(hp, mpg, data=mtcars, shape=am, color=am, size=I(3),
           xlab="Horsepower", ylab="Miles per Gallon") + 
           facet_grid(facets=gear~cyl, scales="free_y")
```

[image: solution]